# AngularJS $http post with scope

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, api

trying to post data to api with php file but it does not seem to work. I am using angular 1.2.9

```
 $scope.submit = function () {


var submitedData = {
  name:  $scope.choise.name,
  image: $scope.choise.image,
  songs: $scope.choices
 }

   $http.post("api/playlist.php",submitedData).success(function(submitedData){
    $scope.choices, $scope.choise.name, $scope.choise.image = submitedData;
   });
    console.log(submitedData);
  }
```

i get 
**Notice**:  Undefined index: type in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Music-Player\api\playlist.php** on line **17**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Music-Player\api\playlist.php** on line **28**
{"success":false}

here is the php file

```
        case 'POST':
          $okresult = false;
            $data = NULL;
            $p =& $_POST;
            if( !empty($p['name']) && !empty($p['image']) && !empty($p['songs']) && is_array($p['songs']) ) {                   
                $okresult = true;
                $c = count($p['songs']);
                for($i=0;$i<$c && $okresult;$i++) {
                    $okresult = !empty($p['songs'][$i]['name']) && !empty($p['songs'][$i]['url']);
                }               
                if($okresult) {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO playlists(name,image,songs) VALUES(:name, :image, :songs)");
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        'name' => $p['name'],
                        'image' => $p['image'],
                        'songs' => json_encode($p['songs'],TRUE)
                    ));
                    $data = [
                        'id' => $conn->lastInsertId()
                    ];
                }               
            }
            response($okresult,$data);
        break;
        default:
            fail(404);
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: So, which one are lines 17 and 28 in playlist.php?

Comment: line 17: if($_GET['type']=='playlist') {

Comment: line 28: playlist_songs($_GET['id']);

Comment: Try setting those values in `submitedData`. For instance: `var submitedData = {
  name:  $scope.choise.name,
  image: $scope.choise.image,
  songs: $scope.choices,
  type: 'playlist',
  id: 123
 }`

Comment: i get the same error..

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize you were doing `$http.post`. So, if you call a `POST`  service, you have to receive the params like this `$_POST['type']` and `$_POST['id']`. Could you try this?

Comment: how to write it with angular?

Comment: How to write what?